# How to group by in mysql without showing duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a search page for babysitter listing and users can filter the results based on wage, distance and rating. Everything works fine, but I am getting three or four results even when there is only 2 people or 1 people and I cannot figure this out.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`                        AS `user_id`, 
       `user_wage_preferences`.`one_child` AS `wage`, 
       `user_contact_informations`.`lat`, 
       `user_contact_informations`.`lng`, 
       `user_reviews`.`rating`, 
       Sum(user_reviews.recommended)       AS recommended, 
       ( 6371 * Acos(Cos(Radians(59.448355500000005)) * Cos(Radians(lat)) * Cos( 
                                   Radians(lng) - Radians(24.7406023)) + 
                              Sin(Radians(59.448355500000005)) * Sin( 
                              Radians(lat))) ) 
                                           AS distance 
FROM   `users` 
       LEFT JOIN `user_reviews` 
              ON `users`.`id` = `user_reviews`.`nanny_id` 
       INNER JOIN `user_wage_preferences` 
               ON `users`.`id` = `user_wage_preferences`.`user_id` 
       INNER JOIN `user_contact_informations` 
               ON `users`.`id` = `user_contact_informations`.`user_id` 
WHERE  `users`.`role` = ? 
       AND `users`.`account_status` = ? 
       AND `users`.`id` IN ( ?, ? ) 
GROUP  BY `user_id`, 
          `user_contact_informations`.`lat`, 
          `user_contact_informations`.`lng`, 
          `user_reviews`.`rating`, 
          `user_wage_preferences`.`one_child` 
HAVING `recommended` > ? 
ORDER  BY `recommended` DESC
```

On my json response I see this:

```
[  
    {  
        "user_id":1,
        "wage":"6",
        "lat":59.44,
        "lng":24.74,
        "rating":5,
        "recommended":"1",
        "distance":0.92971285651468
    },
    {  
        "user_id":4,
        "wage":"4",
        "lat":59.46,
        "lng":24.83,
        "rating":5,
        "recommended":"1",
        "distance":5.2153552636895
    },
    {  
        "user_id":1,
        "wage":"6",
        "lat":59.44,
        "lng":24.74,
        "rating":4,
        "recommended":"0",
        "distance":0.92971285651468
    },
    {  
        "user_id":4,
        "wage":"4",
        "lat":59.46,
        "lng":24.83,
        "rating":1,
        "recommended":"1",
        "distance":5.2153552636895
    }
]
```

As you can see I get `user_id 1` and `user_id 4` twice. And I cannot figure out how to remove the duplicates or group by `user id`.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I show users once?
I am using laravel as a framework.

Comment: use `distinct(`users`.`id`) as id` in select statement

Comment: You are getting multiple results because, you have done group by on "rating" also, it's different in all your duplicate records. Remove it to remove duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different rating in your result.

I can see rating 4, 5 for user1. if you remove rating you will get only one record.

Also you can use group contact to get  multiple ratings as comma separated string - 
GROUP_CONCAT(rating ORDER BY rating ASC)